OneDrive as a background service - Synchronize files when no windows user is logged in
so I am aware of the different tools to transform OneDrive (or any .exe) into a service (WinSW, NSSM, SrvStart, AlwaysUp) and using all 4 of these I managed to have OneDrive appear as a service under "Services", however synchronization does not take place. Currently I have OneDrive running as a service using AlwaysUp, as this program provides a GUI and a bit more information regarding the status.
When starting the service with AlwaysUp I managed to get a bit more information due to the Warning "OneDrive has no network connections to the cloud. It may not be synchronizing your files". When running the service I close the regular OneDrive instance and launch the service under my username that also installed OneDrive and is logged into OneDrive.
I do not know how to establish a connection for OneDrive when it is running as a service.
Any help or alternatives are appreciated.
I tried WinSW, NSSM, SrvStart and AlwaysUp to run OneDrive as a service, and it does show up as a service, however no synchronization takes place.
